# How can i create an equation with a sum?

Tags: equation-solving, summation

I have a list of $p_i$ and the condition that $\sum_{i=0}^{i=69} p_i = 1 $
I also have a list of 69 other different equations. I want to use `NSolve` to solve for the $p_i’s$. `NSolve` Takes a list of equations as an argument. With my current knowledge, I would have to manually type out: $p_0 + p_1 + p_2 +......+p_{69} =1 $. I'm lazy and don't want to do that.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: If `vars = Array[p, 69];` then `Total[vars] == 1` or to normalize their squares use `Total[vars^2] == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked on-line help? Anyway, I would make a list of the variables, and use that. Something like:

```
In[1]:= vars = Table[p[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Out[1]:= {p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]}
In[2]:= eqns = Table[Sum[k^j vars[[k]], {k, 1, 5}] == 3 + j, {j, 0, 4}]
Out[2]:= {p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] == 3, 
 p[1] + 2 p[2] + 3 p[3] + 4 p[4] + 5 p[5] == 4, 
 p[1] + 4 p[2] + 9 p[3] + 16 p[4] + 25 p[5] == 5, 
 p[1] + 8 p[2] + 27 p[3] + 64 p[4] + 125 p[5] == 6, 
 p[1] + 16 p[2] + 81 p[3] + 256 p[4] + 625 p[5] == 7}
In[3]:= Solve[eqns,vars]
Out[3]:={{p[1] -> 11/12, p[2] -> 4, p[3] -> -3, p[4] -> 4/3, p[5] -> -(1/4)}}
```

It may happen that in your case the equations don't come from a formula like in the example above. Somehow I suspect there to be some regularity for I find it unlikely that you would have 69 random equations.

Comment: there is nor problem for the 69 equations, there is a regularity and I used the ```table``` command to wirte those equations out. The problem is writing the $p_0+p_1+p_2+....+p_{69}=1$ equation as I don't want to type out the whole sum. (I used "...." here to denote what I don't want to type)

Comment: @100xln2 But that equation is easy? `Sum[p[k],{k,0,69}]==1` More or less the first equation in my snippet except the number of variables is smaller, and their indexing off by one.

Comment: ahh okay, thank you. This works